# How to understand a null value in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

The Code A comes from the [project](https://github.com/aallam/openai-kotlin.git).
I can't understand completely the code `it.choices.first().delta?.content.orEmpty()`,  is it equivalent to Code B ?

**Code A**

```
openAI.chatCompletions(chatCompletionRequest)
        .onEach { print(it.choices.first().delta?.content.orEmpty()) }
        .onCompletion { println() }
        .launchIn(scope)
        .join()
```

**Code B**

```
if (it.choices.first().delta != null) {
   it.choices.first().delta.content
}else{
   orEmpty()
}
```

BTW, maybe souce code A is wrong, maybe it should be Code C.

**Code C**

```
openAI.chatCompletions(chatCompletionRequest)
        .onEach { print(it.choices.first().delta?.content?.orEmpty()) } //I add a ? after content
        .onCompletion { println() }
        .launchIn(scope)
        .join()
```

Answer (score 2):

`orEmpty()` converts a nullable `String?` to a non-nullable `String` by replacing it with `""` if it is null and otherwise returning the input unchanged. It would be completely useless if you used `?.orEmpty()` because then you wouldn’t be calling the function in the case where it is null so it would have no effect and the resulting expression would still be nullable.

Maybe you don’t realize this, but extension functions can be defined to be callable on nullables. This is an example of one. Another example is the `toString()` extension function, which will return `”null”` if the input is null. This extension function is what makes it possible to call `toString()` on anything.

Your Code B doesn’t make sense. You can’t call `orEmpty()` on nothing (no receiver for the extension function).

Answer (score 1):

The code A a is equivalent to this

```
if (it.choices.first().delta.content != null) {
   it.choices.first().delta.content
}else{
   ""
}
```

`orEmpty` is ext fun that operates on `String?`, if the context is `null` it returns "", and if the context is not null it returns the context.

`it.choices.first().delta?.content` is your context in this example which means output is `String?`. So `orEmpty` operates on this.